# How can I require a node module in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: requirejs, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Consider, for instance, a Python notebook with a `%%javascript` cell. I'd like to use node modules directly, like say THREE.js or D3.js. Ideally I'd like to use node modules globally installed. But, right now, even this doesn't work:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
          paths: {
            THREE: ["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"],
          }
        });

        require(["THREE"], function(THREE){
          console.log("in require");
          window.THREE = THREE;
        });
</script>
```

The console.log should run, I would think, but it's not. And there is no error.